# How do you push updates to a deployed meteor app that has a filesystem?

Tags: meteor

I have an app running on my own digitalocean VM that I'm trying to play around with to figure out how to run a meteor production server.  I deployed it with `meteor build`, but now I'm a bit unsure about how to push updates.  If I build a new tarball on my own machine, I will loose file references that my users have made to files in bundle/uploads, because the remote filesystem isn't incorporated into my local project.  I can imagine some hacky ways to work around this, but besides hosting the files on s3 or another 3rd party server, is there any way to "hot code push" into the deployed app without needing to move files around on my server?

Am I crazy for wondering what the meteor equivalent of git push/pull is in production, or just ignorant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dokku` (https://github.com/progrium/dokku). DigitalOcean allows you to create an instance [pre-installed with dokku too](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-dokku-application).

Once you've set up your ssh keys, set the environment variables, `ROOT_URL`, `PORT` and `MONGO_URL` you can add that server as a git remote and simply `git push` to it.

Dokku will automatically build up the Meteor app and have it running, and keep it up to date whenever you git push.

I find Dokku is very convenient. There's also flynn and deis which are able to do the same in multi tenant environment with way more options.

Just one thing to keep in mind with this is to push the guys who own the repo to keep the [Node version in the buildpack up to date](https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite/pull/61). Meteor is a bit overzealous when it comes to using the latest version of Node and refusing older versions.

Comment: wow, that sounds like exactly what I was looking for!  I'll definitely look into it

Comment: I think the hard truth is that meteor doesn't *want* it to be too easy to deploy their apps on other servers, because they are about to release Galaxy, which will be their managed hosting, and assuming it's competitively priced, I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: That being said Dokku is really cool. I really like using it since its more convenient than `meteor deploy`. The issue is just keeping that Node version up to date. We use a forked repo of the heroku meteorite buildpack to do this.
The other super plus with it is git only uploads file changes which are relatively minute as opposed to the entire project. This was the original reason I started using it

Comment: Yeah, the git pushes you are describe are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor does lack a bit in this department. I can't remember where I may have heard this, but I believe they intend on adding [this very popular](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) Meteor deployment package to their library. Short of switching to a more compatible host, I'm not aware of any better solutions.

Comment: I'm using meteor up in 2 production apps for more than year. Nothing better was created so far.

Comment: `mup deploy`. All assets I keep on S3. I think deploying assets (images, etc ) together with code is not time proof solution.

Comment: Meteor is like this a bit intentionally. They itend to make a commercial product, galaxy, that makes this part easier.

Comment: Haha, just saw that you wrote that @Akshat, I came the the same conclusion